# Debugging help: misplaced \noalign \hline -->\noalign

Tags: tables, fonts

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[T1]{pbsi}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{6}
    \item \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt} 
         \begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|}
         \hline
         \centering Order Form\\
         Name A \dotfill \bsifamily{Green}\\
         Credit Card Number B \dotfill     \\ 
          \hline
           \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

the result is this
[image]

And if I delete the \hline command, the result is this where apparently the font command is overflowing outside of the scope of the braces[image]

Comment: use `\centering\arraybackslash`  so that `\\ ` regains its end-of-table-row meaning or end the row with `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\ `

Comment: Thanks! It works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `\centering\arraybackslash` so that `\\` regains its end-of-table-row meaning or end the row with `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\` (`\centering` locally defines `\\` to mean end a centred line of text)